# How to Escape all Single Double Quotation Marks in Particular .csv Column with Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

- Using Python 2.7.6
- Need solution without use of Pandas Library

I have .csv files with a specific (text) column whose cells occasionally will contain a double quotation mark (").  When converted to shapefiles in ArcMap these single double quotation marks cause an erroneous conversion.  They must be 'escaped'.

I need a script to edit the .csv so that it:

1. replaces all instances of " with "".
2. wraps each cell in double quotation marks.

My script:

```
import csv

with open(Source_CSV, 'r') as file1, open('OUTPUT2.csv','w') as file2:
    reader = csv.reader(file1)  

    # Write column headers without quotes
    headers = reader.next()
    str1 = ''.join(headers)
    writer = csv.writer(file2)
    writer.writerow(headers)

    # Write all other rows with quotes
    writer = csv.writer(file2, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
    for row in reader:
        writer.writerow(row)
```

This script successfully accomplishes BOTH of the above tasks across **ALL** columns.

For example, this original .csv:

```
Column 1, Column 2, Column 3, Column 4 
Fred, Flintstone, 5'10", black hair 
Wilma, Flintstone, five feet seven inches, red hair 
Barney, Rubble, 5 feet 2" inches, blond hair 
Betty, Rubble, 5 foot 7, black hair
```

Becomes this:

```
Column 1, Column 2, Column 3, Column 4
"Fred"," Flintstone"," 5'10"""," black hair"
"Wilma"," Flintstone"," five feet seven inches"," red hair"
"Barney"," Rubble"," 5 feet 2"" inches"," blond hair"
"Betty"," Rubble"," 5 foot 7"," black hair"
```

But what if I want to accomplish this in the **3rd column ONLY** (the one that actually has double quotation marks occasionally)?

In other words, how can I end up with this...?

```
Column 1, Column 2, Column 3, Column 4
Fred, Flintstone," 5'10""", black hair
Wilma, Flintstone," five feet seven inches", red hair
Barney, Rubble," 5 feet 2"" inches", blond hair
Betty, Rubble," 5 foot 7", black hair
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it sufficient to only quote fields that have a double quote in them?  If so the default behavior of the `csv` module will work, although I added `skipinitialspace=True` when parsing the input file so it won't treat the space after the commas as significant.

Also per the `csv` module documentation, I've opened the files in binary mode.

```
import csv

with open('input.csv','rb') as file1, open('output.csv','wb') as file2:
    reader = csv.reader(file1,skipinitialspace=True)  
    writer = csv.writer(file2)

    for row in reader:
        writer.writerow(row)
```

Input:

```
Column 1, Column 2, Column 3, Column 4
Fred, Flintstone, 5'10", black hair
Wilma, Flintstone, five feet seven inches, red hair
Barney, Rubble, 5 feet 2" inches, blond hair
Betty, Rubble, 5 foot 7, black hair
```

Output:

```
Column 1,Column 2,Column 3,Column 4
Fred,Flintstone,"5'10""",black hair
Wilma,Flintstone,five feet seven inches,red hair
Barney,Rubble,"5 feet 2"" inches",blond hair
Betty,Rubble,5 foot 7,black hair
```

If you require quoting every row of column 3, then you can do so manually.  I've set the `csv` module to quote nothing, and set the quote character to an unprintable control character that shouldn't appear in the input:

```
import csv

with open('input.csv','rb') as file1, open('output.csv','wb') as file2:
    reader = csv.reader(file1,skipinitialspace=True)
    writer = csv.writer(file2,quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE,quotechar='\x01')

    # Write column headers without quotes
    headers = reader.next()
    writer.writerow(headers)

    # Write 3rd column with quotes
    for row in reader:
        row[2] = '"' + row[2].replace('"','""') + '"'
        writer.writerow(row)
```

Output:

```
Column 1,Column 2,Column 3,Column 4
Fred,Flintstone,"5'10""",black hair
Wilma,Flintstone,"five feet seven inches",red hair
Barney,Rubble,"5 feet 2"" inches",blond hair
Betty,Rubble,"5 foot 7",black hair
```

Comment: Thanks for the two options.  Also the tip to use skipinitialspace and the reminder to use binary mode.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
    import csv
with open("file.csv", "rU") as fin:
    words = fin.readlines()

with open("cleaned.csv", "w") as fout:
    writer = csv.writer(fout, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL, quotechar = '"', doublequote = True)
    for row in words:
        row = row.replace("\n", "")
        newrow = []
        for word in row.split(","): 
            newrow.append(word.strip())
        writer.writerow(newrow)
```

First with open attemps to read it as a simple text file to bypass the badly formatted csv file. And then we write it to a csv file normally.

Comment: thanks.  both yours and mine reach the same result: all fields across all columns wrapped in double quotes and double quotes doubled.  But how can that solution be applied to ONLY one column of your choice?